# Conditional select if exists

Tags: select, informix, exists

I would like to have SQL code to validate if table [grlf_lig] exists than select fields,  how can I do it on informix?

I use sheel code for the validation but it is slow, because it have to record files on disk and make validations.

```
dbaccess sysmaster <<EOF  > /dev/null 2> /dev/null
set isolation to dirty read;
unload  to '$TMPFILE' delimiter "|"
select x0.sid,
x0.username,
x0.hostname,
x1.sqs_dbname,
dbinfo("UTC_TO_DATETIME",x0.connected) AS conn_dt
from
sysmaster:"informix".syssessions x0,
sysmaster:"informix".syssqlstat x1,
sysmaster:"informix".sysnetworkio n
where ( x0.sid = x1.sqs_sessionid ) and hostname is not NULL  and 
trim(hostname) <> ''
and trim(hostname) <> '-' AND sqs_dbname NOT LIKE 'sys%' AND sqs_dbname <> 
'-' AND n.sid = x0.sid
EOF

for I in `cat $TMPFILE`; do

 SID=`echo $I | awk -F'|' '{print $1}'`
 BD=`echo $I | awk -F'|' '{print $4}'`
 echo "" > $FILE
 dbaccess $BD <<EOF  > /dev/null 2> /dev/null
 set isolation to dirty read;
 unload to "$FILE" delimiter '|'
 select first 1 sid_f_lig, max(dtlogin_f_lig), winuser_f_lig, tty_f_lig, 
 cod_capli from grlf_lig where
 ( sid_f_lig = '$SID' and dtlogout_f_lig is null )
 group by  sid_f_lig, winuser_f_lig, tty_f_lig, cod_capli
 EOF

 if [ -s $FILE ]; then
    cat $FILE >> $FILE1
 fi
 done
```

I would like to get results fast, because it takes long times to get results.

Comment: You need to provide more information. The sysmaster query should be very fast, so you should add some logging to your shell script and see where it is spending the most time (maybe it is the overhead of creating a new session for every query, maybe the query to the `grlf_lig` is slow. One possibility to speed up things is to create a stored procedure to make use of dynamic sql to query each database.

Comment: I have already done it and verified that most time was spent on sorting operation and getting values for the second query. What I pretend in this case, is using exists clause to verify if table exists than get the values.

Comment: You cannot do a `SELECT` if table exists in Informix SQL. You will always have to do a separate check for the table existence and then query the table. You can use a stored procedure for that or do it in the shell script (maybe simply check if the select errors out with a table does not exist code). Anyway, if it is the second query that is taking time, check the `explain` of the query to see if you can speed it up (maybe an index is missing).

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I will take a look but my biggest problem is always to have to do disk access. My idea was to avoid that if possible off course.